# R: boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular') with lrem model - only when transforming data to log

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, data-transformation, logarithm, boundary

I am trying to run a lmer model on my dataset.

**My dataset :**

str(tabfi)

```
'data.frame':   240 obs. of  9 variables:
 $ Mix    : Factor w/ 3 levels "B","C","S": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Origin : Factor w/ 2 levels "L","NL": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Bloc   : Factor w/ 2 levels "GS","PS": 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Rep    : Factor w/ 10 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ Indiv  : Factor w/ 60 levels "BL1","BL10","BL2",..: 1 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 2 ...
 $ Week   : int  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Day    : Factor w/ 4 levels "11","18","34",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ A_forb : num  30 80 32 27 24 24 33 23 21 29 ...
 $ A_forbL: num  3.4 4.38 3.47 3.3 3.18 ...
```

summary(tabfi)

```
 B:80   L :120   GS:120   1      :24   BL1    :  4   Min.   :2.00   Min.   :11.00   Min.   :  9.0  
 C:80   NL:120   PS:120   2      :24   BL10   :  4   1st Qu.:2.75   1st Qu.:16.25   1st Qu.: 47.0  
 S:80                     3      :24   BL2    :  4   Median :4.00   Median :26.00   Median : 96.0  
                          4      :24   BL3    :  4   Mean   :4.00   Mean   :25.75   Mean   :129.5  
                          5      :24   BL4    :  4   3rd Qu.:5.25   3rd Qu.:35.50   3rd Qu.:196.0  
                          6      :24   BL5    :  4   Max.   :6.00   Max.   :40.00   Max.   :528.0  
                          (Other):96   (Other):216
```

A_forbL is simply a log transformation of A_forb.

**The model I am trying to run :**
`LMERafi = lmer(A_forbL ~ Day * Mix * Origin + Bloc + (1|Indiv), data=tabfi)`

**The situation :**

The model is running perfectly with A_forb, but when applying the log transformation, the console returns the following error :
*boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular')*

I have also tried simplifying the expression with all the variations between :

`LMERafi = lmer(A_forbL ~ (Day + Mix + Origin)^2 + Bloc + (1|Indiv), data=tabfi)`

and

`LMERafi = lmer(A_forbL ~ 1 + (1|Indiv), data=tabfi)`

Nothing works. However, the model runs OK when using a `lm` and deleting the `+ (1|Indiv)` term (which must keep btw).

The exact same model runs perfectly with other data of mine.

My dispositive is balanced and I don't have "0" values.

I cannot figure out where the problem is coming from. I already encountered the same issue on non-transformed data that seemingly "magically" solved itself when restarting the PC (???).

I'd appreciate is anyone could help me on this one.
Thanks in advance.